# Unable to access new core data attribute in code

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I've added a new attribute to an entity called `minimumOrderValue`, but when I try to read or write to it on code, it raises the exception `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2831a1040'` and terminates the app.

It is of type Decimal, and it is declared like so in the swift file (I'm updating the swift files manually for several reasons):

```
@NSManaged var minimumOrderValue: Decimal
```

I created a new model version before creating the attribute.

I wonder what the problem would be.

Comment: Did you set the new model version as the currently used version ? The model which has a green checkmark is the current active version. Have a look at https://cocoacasts.com/migrating-a-data-model-with-core-data and scroll down the section `Versioning the Data Model`. If you have done this, please ignore this comment.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode doesn’t update the built binaries properly after changing the model so another thing to try is to clean the build folder (and possibly also the derived data folder)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The version was being set programatically somewhere else in the code, instead of being updated automatically.